# Querying a large dynamodb table for similar values

Tags: python, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

We have a large dynamodb database (approx. 4.5 mil entries) that we are trying to query similar hash values from.

The table has the image path (primary key), md5hash, and ahash. We want to query for similar md5hashes or ahashes from new items we receive in our search.

However, as far as I can see for dynamodb_client.get_object() a primary key must be used, and I'm not finding any way to even search for an equal hash, let alone a similar one.

My current workaround is to run Table.scan(), pull the information into a pandas DataFrame (using python), then run a difflib filter on that new dataframe table.

Doing that is expensive, to say the least, and also slow. Does anyone have any other ideas how we might make this work?

Thank you!

Comment: What is a "similar" hash? And yes, this is generally not doable in a dynamodb - dynamodb is a key-value store with sorting capabilities and local and global secondary indices. If you cannot reduce your problem to a get or query operation based on an index and / or sorting then dynamodb cannot help you.

Comment: @luk2302 We changed the hash similarities to using hamming differences but that aside, I think we've decided to migrate to postgres due to costs and also due to its simplicity in pulling it into dataframes. We already maintain a number of postgres databases, so its preferable.

Comment: Okay, that is absolutely impossible in dynamodb.